# topcoder arena editor save path?

Tags: java, editor

I'm using [`kawigiedit`](http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/KawigiEdit/KawigiEdit.html) in topcoder arena,  but I want to save the source code to my workplace path.
I have not found an option in kawigiedit to configure `the path to save the code`.
Is there any way to specify it or other editors to configure the path?
(I don't want to use Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a hard work in google searching and found one, not perfect but useful:[Greed Edit](https://github.com/shivawu/topcoder-greed)
But I've seen someone use **something just named "editor"** in the arrena in a vedio record.
Some better suggestions?

PS: [see here](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=F741DFF9CDB52F130930D383942B87D0?module=Thread&threadID=597911&start=0&mc=74#992265)

Answer (score 1):

Click configure

[image]

In the first tab, under General and browse to select your folder

[image]

Voila! your code will sync automatically to your desired folder.